# How prove that $(DB+BC)^2=AD^2+AC^2$ in convex quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a convex quadrilateral,and write $\alpha =\angle DAB,\beta =\angle ADB,\gamma =\angle ACB,\delta =\angle DBC , \epsilon =\angle DBA. $ Assuming that $\alpha <\frac{\pi}{2},\beta +\gamma =\frac{\pi}{2},\delta +2\epsilon =\pi$.
How prove that $(DB+BC)^2=AD^2+AC^2$?

Comment: Could you provide a picture (you can make one using geogebra for example)?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PAOwKrV.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $C'$ as the mirror image of $C$ with respect to the line $AB$.
We have that $D,B,C'$ are collinear, hence we just need to prove that $\widehat{DAC'}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in order to prove our claim through the pythagorean theorem. Symmetry gives:
$$\widehat{BC'A}=\widehat{ACB}=\gamma,$$
but since $\beta+\gamma=\pi/2$, $\,\widehat{DAC'}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ as wanted.

[image: The "folded" pythagorean theorem]